# I dont understand chain rule for multivariable calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

The question is:

Suppose that the equations $rz^3+sz=t$ and $\sin(s+t)=rs$ determine $z$ as a function of $r,s,t$ and $s$ as a function of $r$ and $t$. Hence, $z$ can be treated as a function $z=f(r,t)$. Find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$.

The answer key writes:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial s}\frac{\partial s}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial t}$$

I dont understand why the chain rule is as such.

Comment: The question tells you right there. You can ignore the equations they don't have anything to do with this part. The question tells you that $z$ is a function of $s, r, t$ and that $s$ is a function of $r, t$.

Comment: The answer key uses notation which really does not make sense. But what's being used here is the implicit function theorem (and chain rule). The chain rule says $g(h(x))'=g'(h(x))h'(x)$, does that help?

Comment: @Andrew. The notation used is okay, however, perhaps this might be clearer.  $$\begin{align}\dfrac{\partial f(r,t)}{\partial t\hspace{5ex}}&=\dfrac{\partial z(r,s,t)}{\partial s\hspace{7ex}}\cdotp\dfrac{\partial s(r,t)}{\partial t\hspace{5ex}}+\dfrac{\partial z(r,s,t)}{\partial t\hspace{7ex}}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

$z = z(s,r,t)$, and $s = s(r,t)$, so $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial s}\frac{\partial s}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial t}\\
= \frac{\partial z}{\partial s}\frac{\partial s}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial r}0 + \frac{\partial z}{\partial t}1$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp - I'm sorry, but I disagree with your changes. While not false, they seem to me to make my key point less clear, not more.

Comment: What is $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial t}$ ?  You use it to mean two different operations.  On the LHS you are differentiating with respect to $t$ treating $r$ as independent, while on the RHS you are differentiating with respect to $t$ treating $r$ *and* $s$ as independent.

Comment: @GrahamKemp - No. It is the same meaning. It is exactly because it is the same meaning that I can say $\frac{\partial t}{\partial t} = 1$. It could perhaps be clarified more by introducing two more variables $u(r,r) = r, v(r,t) = t$, then consider $z = z(s, u, v)$ and write it as $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial s}\frac{\partial s}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}$$But there is still a problem with recognizing that $\frac{\partial z}{\partial v} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial t}$.

Comment: No, they are distinct.  Unless you are trying to claim $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial s}{\partial t}$ equals $0$ .

Comment: @GrahamKemp - You will have to explain how, and why in the world you could even think such a thing. I cannot find even a shred of sense in it.

Comment: Because you insist on writing $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial t}=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial s}{\partial t}+\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial t}$

Comment: Horrendous classic abuse of notation. Graham is correct. Use a different letter for $z(r,s(r,t),t)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin - Interesting phrasing. What I am using is the *classic* notation. Your demanded version is an adaption of that notation to set-theoretic functions made around 200 years later. But the classic interpretation is still in wide use, as the usage that inspired it in the first place is still needed: having a group of variables - physical measurements - that are related, so there exist equations that they satisfy. Which are functions of which is a matter of how you choose to look at the situation.